# Matplotlib: Fitting x axis labels into the figure for bar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a bar plot for a categorical data; which containts 173 different categories. I want to fit the whole data into a single figure. The code is like the following:

```
        series = self.mainDataFrame[cat_col].value_counts()
        columns = series.index.to_list()
        values = series.values
        y_pos = np.arange(len(columns))
        plt.bar(y_pos, values, align='center', alpha=0.5)
        plt.xticks(y_pos, columns, fontsize='xx-small')
        plt.ylabel('Frequency')
        plt.title("Categorical Column:{0}".format(cat_col))
```

This is the result I get:

[image]

I want two things mainly; I want the x-axis labels to be readable (each of them consists of three letter words) and the bars to not be that cluttered, such that some of them are rendered as glued together. I tried to enlarge the figure width while keeping bar widths the same but I failed. For the label font size, this is what I get even with `plt.xticks(y_pos, columns, fontsize='xx-small')`. How can I make this figure more readable?

Comment: can rotate tick labels, see [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/ticks_and_spines/ticklabels_rotation.html)

Comment: Actually, I tried that too but the labels are still overlapped.

Comment: how many bars you have ? can u provide some toy data ?

Comment: Perhaps you can exclude half of the x-axis using `plt.xlim`. Their frequency appears to be non-existent.

Comment: you must have every lablels on the axes ? or you can ignore some?

Comment: I think I solved the issue by stuffing all low frequency categories into a "Others" category for now, thanks for all suggestions.